# High CPU usage due to Microsoft IME (Chinese)

Tags: windows-10, cpu

I am running Windows 10 Professional on a 3-year old Thinkpad laptop, and the process named as `Microsoft IME` has been constantly consuming around 30% of my CPU. After looking up what IME means, it seems it is referring to the Input Method Editor. This process is running with high CPU consumption *at all times*, even when I am not using the Chinese input methods.

[image]

Is the IME related to input methods? To avoid this constant energy and CPU consumption, should I uninstall the Chinese input method? The input methods I have installed are as follows:

[image]

Comment: FYI: https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/55ny3x/microsoft_ime_high_cpu_use_after_20160929_update/d8c5y18/

Comment: Open a cmd.exe as admin, run the following command: **wpr.exe -start CPU && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl**. When you see the high CPU usage, wait 30s and press a key to stop logging. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you for pointing out what I need to prepare for debugging this particular issue. In the mean time, I have found a compromise, as posted.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Solution

### Acknowledgement

Thanks to @Jon, this [riddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/55ny3x/microsoft_ime_high_cpu_use_after_20160929_update/d8c5y18/) could have potentially *solved* the exact problem. However, due to the concerns listed under the same Riddit post, I have postponed to practice their solutions on my obsolete laptop.

### MY partial solution (not working yet)

Like most bugs on Windows OS, restarting the machine/process should solve the problem. Here goes a piece of [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) script that does only one thing: "kill the process named `ChsIME.exe`". My Windows 10 OS have managed to start a new instance of this process right after the termination of the previous process.

```
; Kill the Windows IME process using keyboard shortcut -- Alt+Ctrl+Shift+I
^!+i::
    process, exist, ChsIME.exe
    pid = %ErrorLevel%
    Process, Close, %pid%
return
```

I am aware that this is by far not a clean solution, and I will post my system logs of high CPU usage when it happens next time.

## System logs when ChiIME.exe is using up to 34% of CPU

https://www.dropbox.com/s/trkl647cbc6epjt/HighCPUUsage.zip?dl=0

### Observation: SYSTEM is running that high-CPU ChsIME.exe process

[image]

Comment: I can see that the ChsIME.exe (15008) is calling a server and doing Advanced Local Procedure Call (ALPC) calls, but no idea how to fix this. submit te issue in the feedback hub app and include a link to the ETL

Answer (score 0):

Let me post what solved this issue in my case, please notice it might be a *very specific interaction of IME*, but I thought it might helps others in similar situation.

I was going nuts due to `ChsIME.exe` getting constant high CPU (kinda loop-buggy), but looking closer I also found my antivirus eating CPU as well. Somebody suggested to disable the antivirus but it would not disable itself [in this case Avast Behaviour Shield] as it keeps looping as well.

I uninstalled the IME keyboard extension temporarily (Win 10, `Language and keyboard options`), and as soon as I killed the consuming IME process the antivirus stopped itself and the CPU went down to idle - wow so that's interesting, who's fault is it?

Comment: I guess it can also be a machine/"customized"-OS problem. In partiular for a newer Lenovo T480 laptop, I can get 2 hours of battery life with "Windows 10 OS from Microsoft" and 4+ hours of battery life from "Windows 10 - Downloaded from Lenovo's OS-distribution system". A tone of other processes should be involved. **I would suggest going with a proper Windows OS first**, then _debug_ the processes :)